# Как правильно работать с абстрактными классами в Qt? Как работать с несколькими классами в Qt?

Tags: qt, c++, классы

Я не понимаю как работать с абстрактными классами виджетов в Qt.
Мне нужно написать простое приложение, которое состоит из одного QLabel и QLineEdit.
Задача - прикрепить к QLineEdit QValidator для того, что бы отсечь цифры при вводе.
Но компилятор ругается на то, что не может выделить объект абстрактного класса QValidator.
Как решить эту проблему, что я делаю не так?

И еще один вопрос, возможно не много не по теме. До текущего момента я писал такие же небольшие приложения с одним базовым классом, стараясь запихнуть в реализацию класса как можно больше. То есть, для базового класса все виджеты и сигналы определялись еще в конструкторе и в заголовочном файле.
Когда же я писал этот код, в конструктор абстрактного класса виджеты засунуть не получилось, а связать его с другим базовым классом унаследованным от QWidget как с отцовским классом, тоже не выходит. 
Как корректней писать приложения, реализовывать все в одном классе или в нескольких и если да то как их правильно разносить между собой?

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mainwidget.h"
#include "namevalidator.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QVBoxLayout>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    mainWidget w;

    QLabel *lblText = new QLabel("&Name (The digits will not be accepted!)");
    QLineEdit *lineText = new QLineEdit;
    NameValidator *nmVal = new NameValidator(lineText);

    lineText->setValidator(nmVal);
    lblText->setBuddy(lineText);

    //Layout setup
    QVBoxLayout *vBox = new QVBoxLayout;
    vBox->addWidget(lblText);
    vBox->addWidget(lineText);
    w.setLayout(vBox);
    w.show();

    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**mainwidget.cpp**

```
#include "mainwidget.h"

mainWidget::mainWidget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    spBox = new QSpinBox;
    spBox->setRange(1, 100);
    spBox->setSuffix(" MB");
    spBox->setButtonSymbols(QSpinBox::PlusMinus);
    spBox->setWrapping(true);
    spBox->show();
    spBox->resize(50, 30);

    dtBox = new QDateTimeEdit(QDateTime::currentDateTime());

    vBox = new QVBoxLayout;
    vBox->addWidget(spBox);
    vBox->addWidget(dtBox);

    setLayout(vBox);
    resize(200, 40);
}

mainWidget::~mainWidget()
{

}
```

**mainwidget.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWIDGET_H
#define MAINWIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QSpinBox>
#include <QDateTimeEdit>
#include <QVBoxLayout>

class mainWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    mainWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~mainWidget();

private:
    QSpinBox *spBox;
    QDateTimeEdit *dtBox;
    QVBoxLayout *vBox;
};

#endif // MAINWIDGET_H
```

**namevalidator.h**

```
#ifndef NAMEVALIDATOR_H
#define NAMEVALIDATOR_H

#include <QValidator>
#include <QString>
#include <QRegExp>

class NameValidator : public QValidator
{
public:
    NameValidator(QObject *parent);

    virtual State validate(QString str, int& pos) const
    {
        QRegExp rxp = QRegExp("[0-9]");
        if (str.contains(rxp)) {
            return Invalid;
        }

        return Acceptable;
    }
};

#endif // NAMEVALIDATOR_H
```

**namevalidator.cpp**

```
#include "namevalidator.h"

NameValidator::NameValidator(QObject *parent)
    : QValidator(parent)
{
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Абстрактные классы (не только в QT) нужны, чтобы унаследовать свой класс от них, следуя их логике. Абстрактные классы для того и нужны, чтобы "подсказать" каким должен быть ваш класс и описывает схему вызовов функций, которые вам еще предстоит описать в классе наследнике. Если вы создали унаследованный класс от абстрактого, в нем должны быть описаны все абстрактные функции родителя, а то класс так и останется абстрактным (в частности ваш класс NameValidator). А создать **объект** абстрактного класса невозможно согласно синтаксису языка и это правильно!
В классе NameValidator потребуется описать **все** абстрактные методы QValidator

---

Пихать все в один класс неправильно, есть даже такой "антипаттерн" вроде. Чтобы "разносить" между собой разные классы программисты C++ традиционно использовали членами класса указатели на объекты друг-друга. В QT появилось такое замечательное средство как сигналы и слоты, с помощью них вообще прекрасно получается классы "разносить".